# Bash script to iterate over files recursively and use matches from regex

Tags: bash, shell

I have a directory that contains many sub-directories. Inside all these sub-folders we have *.yml files.

The files names are something like:

```
file-name-daily-1.yml
file-name-daily-2.yml
file-name-weekly-1.yml
file-name-weekly-2.yml
file-name-monthly-1.yml
```

Inside each file there is a line like:

```
- name: Some line of text here
```

I have a command that looks like:

```
node index.js --epr --run "[my matched string]" -p $D -p $F -p $T
```

I would need a bash script that will recursively search the directories for files containing a keyword (daily, weekly, monthly, 1, 2, etc.) and then grab the text following the ":" inside the matched files. I would then need to run my command against each match.

How would this great community go about doing such a task?

Comment: This great community would probably first ask: have you looked at the `find` and `sed` commands? :)

Comment: Indeed I have, but I'm a newbie to bash and haven't been able to put together a working command just yet. Closest I've come is a grep command that outputs ALL matches nondiscriminatory...

grep -rohIP '^- name:\K(.*)$'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done without a loop as a follows:

```
find DIR/ -name *.yml -exec sh -c "grep '\- name\:.*' {} | sed 's/\-name:\(.*\)/\1/'| xargs -I '{}' yourcommand --yourargument {}" \;
```

where `yourcommand` would be replaced by the command you want to run with the results of `find`.

This script first `find`s the files matched by the wildcard expression.

It then executes a command which uses `grep` to find the relevant line of the file, and modifies the output using `sed` to gain just the relevent text.

Finally the arguments are piped into `yourcommand` with the placeholder `{}` taking the place of the argument.

Your can test the code using

```
find DIR/ -name *.yml -exec sh -c "grep "^\- name:" {} | sed 's/\-name:\(.*\)/\1/' | xargs -I '{}' echo \"node index.js --epr --run {} -p $F -p $T -p $D1\"" \;
```

and remove the `echo` once you are happy with the results.

Comment: Thank you. Running this gets me the output I would expect but I'm not sure how to run the command using xargs.`#!/bin/bash

F="parameters.fromDate=2018-02-01 00:00:00"
T="parameters.toDate=2018-02-28 23:59:59"
D="some@email.domain"
P="*-daily*"

runFunc() {
    echo node index.js --epr --run $1 -p $F -p $T -p $D
}

find . -name $pattern -exec sh -c "grep '^\- name\:.*' {} | sed 's/\- name:\(.*\)/\1/'| xargs -I '{}' runFunc {}" \;` This outputs the error: "find: paths must precede expression: sh"

Comment: @cw84 try this `find DIR/ -name *.yml -exec sh -c "grep "^\-name:" {} | sed 's/\-name:\(.*\)/\1/' | xargs -I '{}' echo \"~node index.js --epr --run {} -p $F -p $T -p $D1\"" \;` and take the echo out once you are happy with the results!

Comment: I think I almost have it... I am using: `#!/bin/bash
F="2018-02-01 00:00:00"
T="2018-02-28 23:59:59"
P="*3b*monthly*"
find . -name "$P.yml" -type f -exec sh -c "grep '^\- name\:.*' {} | sed 's/\- name:\(.*\)/\1/'| xargs -I '{}' echo \"~node index.js --epr --run {} -p $F -p $T\"" \;`There are 3 files in this searched directory that should return output.

Comment: My output looks like this however: `$ ../output_files.sh
 -p 2018-02-01 00:00:00 -p 2018-02-28 23:59:59uping Report
 -p 2018-02-01 00:00:00 -p 2018-02-28 23:59:59nt Report
~node index.js --epr --run 3b Monthly Health Report -p 2018-02-01 00:00:00 -p 2018-02-28 23:59:59` ... it appears to not return or handle the names correctly. Any idea why?

Comment: Sorry I left an errant tilde in the above expression, which I have corrected in my answer.  I could not reproduce your output with a test file - so it is possibly something to do with the particular format of the names in the `*.yml` files. Sample output for me was: `node index.js --epr --run -name: Monthly Health Report -p 2018-02-01 00:00:00 -p 2018-02-28 23:59:59
node index.js --epr --run -name: mytexthere -p 2018-02-01 00:00:00 -p 2018-02-28 23:59:59`

Comment: If I use what you have I don't get it to return lines recursively. It only outputs what is in the current directory. I'll need it to find in all sub-directories as well. I also tried to change `-name *.yml` to `-name "$pattern.yml"`, this is where it starts to mess up the output. I can assign `pattern="*"` and it successfully returns lines recursively now, but the output is wonky.

Comment: @cw84 the command should look recursively through all subdirectories of `DIR` (or in this case `.`) for files (not directories) matching `*.yml`. I'm sorry, I'm not sure what could be causing these issues in the output, based on the information. As I could not reproduce this with what was above, perhaps you could edit the question with some additional information and what you have tried with a minimal working example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173078/discussion-between-david-and-cw84).

Answer (score 1):

Likely using `find` as lurker mentioned.

```
pattern="*-daily*"

for match in $(find . -name $pattern -exec grep '\- name:' {} \; | awk -F ': ' '{print $2}'); do
    node index.js --epr --run "${match}" -p $D -p $F -p $T
done
```

Comment: `grep x | awk '{ y }'` is usualdy better written `awk '/x/ { y }'`. See also [useless use of `grep`](http://www.ik.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand awk very well, but it looks like I am getting results that are only the first word following the ":" in the matched string. I need all the text following the ":". Also, the file contains multiple "- name" matches so I need to anchor that as the start of the line. I think I managed to do that changing your grep command to: grep '^\- name:' {} \;